# What does the text in the Ghost's schematics say?

Tags: star-wars

Starwars.com have published [an image of Hera's ship](http://web.archive.org/web/20141208013614/http://www.starwars.com/news/join-the-rebellion) *The Ghost* from the new Disney canon:

What was the text (presumably in Galactic Standard) on that schematic?

[image]

Comment: FYI: Some of the text (especially the lower right corner tech specs) seem to be copied into the specs onto [Wookiepedia page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text is [Aurebesh](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aurebesh/Canon), the *Star Wars* alphabet:

The text at the bottom left of the diagram reads:

> MODIFIED VCX-100 LIGHT FREIGHTER

The text at the bottom-right of the diagram, under the insignia, reads:

> CORRELIAN ENGINEERING CORPORATION

The bottom-left quadrant of the image reads:

> 1.NOSE TURRET ?<sup>1</sup> S<sup>2</sup> UNNER STATION<sup>3</sup>
>   2. FORWARD FLOODLIGHTS
>   3. MAIN COCKPIT
>   4. CREW QUARTERS
>   5. PORT DOCKING RING
>   6. STARBOARD DOCKING RING
>   7. DORSAL LASER CANNON TURRET
>   8. MAIN CARGO HOLD
>   9. ENGINE ASSEMBLY

The bottom-right quadrant reads:

> METRICS
>   LENGTH 43.9 METERS
>   WIDTH 34.2 METERS
>   LENGTH 14.5 METERS

---

<sup>1</sup> The character here appears to be a punctuation mark, which doesn't have an entry in any translation table I've been able to find

<sup>2</sup> I know, it doesn't make sense to me either. But that's the character that's there. It's all the more confusing because of the spacing; the 'S' character appears to be a full space between it and the preceding punctuation mark, but only a half-space between it and the following character; judging by the "Metrics" section, it seems customary to place a space following a punctuation mark, but I'm not sure what to make of the half-space.

<sup>3</sup> This was the hardest line to translate, so what's above is a direct transliteration. Doing some intuitive error-correcting, there are two main possibilities for what it's *meant* to say:

- "NOSE TURRET'S GUNNER STATION"
- "NOSE TURRET & GUNNER STATION"

No idea which is correct, but everything you need to know is there anyway

Comment: Wow. You scary, man.