# What is this symbol on the Ghost

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

What is this symbol on the *Ghost*? It's located on the side (possibly only the left) of the front loading bay.

[image: A mysterious symbol on the Ghost]

Comment: I suspect it’s got to be a model or class designation. [This answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/81523/51379) shows that the text beneath it in the schematics says “Corellian Engineering Corporation,” but we don’t see anything like that on the *Millenium Falcon*, nor I think other CEC ships.

Comment: I've looked into it. There hasn't been much mention of it online but [this post](http://fanofthewars.com/first-star-wars-rebels-merchandise-arrives/) seems to imply that it's the Ghost's symbol (not a model). I tried [tweeting  at Adam Bray](https://twitter.com/authoradambray/status/794641881812574208) (the author of the rebels visual guide) who said that Dave Filoni has addressed it, but I have yet to find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's the symbol of the *Ghost***

This symbol first appeared on a pin given to people who attended the *Star Wars: Rebels* panel at *Star Wars Celebration Europe 2013*

[image: A pin with the symbol on it]

[This Blog post](http://fanofthewars.com/first-star-wars-rebels-merchandise-arrives/) and [a post in this thread](http://boards.theforce.net/threads/official-star-wars-rebels-discussion-thread-spoilers-allowed.50011239/page-823) suggest that the people who got the pins knew that the symbol was that of the Ghost. Seeing as how the show didn't air until 2014, someone official probably told them what the symbol was.

Just to note: the pin included a hidden url that lead to an early version of the  picture in @Adamant 's post.

Furthermore, the symbol has 2 elements that lend itself to being uniquely the *Ghost*:

[image: Crazy theories]

1. Two green triangular tear drop shapes, and then 2 smaller green lines below that resemble Hera's leku (head tails). Remember, the Ghost is Hera's ship.
2. The shape of the symbol is reminiscent of the ship. (Octagon)

All this together leads me to believe that this is the symbol of the Ghost itself (and not of the VCX-100)

I used [ColonialChrome's ghost reference](http://colonialchrome.deviantart.com/art/The-Ghost-Exterior-503756450) in the picture above.

Answer (score 7):

### Probably a model symbol

According to the schematics from *Star Wars Rebels: The Visual Guide*:

[image]

The [Aurabesh](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aurebesh) text above the logo seems to read:

[image]

(Note that the cresh is backwards in my version, for some reason).

Or, in English, line-by-line:

> VCX-100
>
> LIGHT
>
> FREIGHTER

That is, of course, the [ship](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/VCX-100_light_freighter) from which the *Ghost* was originally modified.

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/81523/51379) might suggest  that it is the logo of the Corellian Engineering Corporation, since that is the text that appears below the symbol in the image presented there. However, this logo does does not appear on the *Millenium Falcon* or other ships manufactured by the CEC, so this seems unlikely.

Comment: Brilliant, brilliant, brilliant! +1